# Need help to read xml data to correct storage in c++?

Tags: c++

I need to read an xml file and store it in a map or any suitable storage. My final stored data will be like,

```
key1 | value1
key2 | value2
key3 | inner value1
       inner value2
       inner value3
```

Could you please suggest a possible storage in c++ ? I am very new to this C++ coding.

Comment: why this question got 2 down votes? is it a wrong question or not understandable?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>`